# Cancel operation if input number in edittext is negative

Tags: java, android, negative-number

I'm making a calculator where there is only one edittext to input the number. The result is displayed in a textview and there is 1 button for addition only. I'm stuck in how can i stop it from adding if the input number is negative. If i inputted a negative number and click the addition button it will display a toast and will minus itself to the current value. I want it to stop adding if the input is negative.

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            first=et1.getText().toString();
            int val;

        if (first.isEmpty()){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please enter a number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            val=Integer.parseInt(et1.getText().toString());
           int we=Integer.parseInt(t1.getText().toString());

            if (Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(val))<=0){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Value must not be negative", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                et1.setText("");
            }else{
            int ans=val+we;
            t1.setText(""+ans);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You have added "+et1.getText().toString()+" to the current value", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }}


        }
    });
```

Comment: b1 is the addition button you're talking about?

Comment: yes, b1 @LawrenceGimenez

Comment: What toast will display if number is negative?

Comment: you can do simply this `if(val < 0){  // val is negative }`.